# URL Forward slash displaced in browser

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, mozilla

So i deployed my java application and everything works fine except when i click a link or type the full url (example: https://url.com/login?key=qwerasd) the browser shows error page title "This site cannot be reached" with the url showing the the forward slash removed thus making the full url appear this way: https://url.comlogin/?key=qwerasd.

I would like to know if anyone has encountered this issue and know how to resolve it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whether this issue only occurs in special browser, or all of the browsers will not work? Try to check the website using different browser. If the website not working in all of the browsers, perhaps the issue is related to your website routing configure, please check your code. If this issue only occurs in a special browser, try to clear the browser data (cache, cookie and so on), then recheck whether it works well.

Comment: Checked all browsers including chrome, internet explorer and mobile browsers and when you follow a link or type the url it gives that error however if you make edits to the url after the error, everything works out just fine. Dont understand why this is so

Comment: Perhaps the issue is related to the Application routing configuration, please check this part of the code.